# Are the Japanese し and the Mandarin "xi" really both [ɕ]?

Tags: phonology, phonetics

I've had this question for several months now, and haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer online.

The Japanese し and the Mandarin "xi", as in 西, are listed equivalently as [[ɕ] in the IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolo-palatal_sibilant).

However, my girlfriend and I can fairly clearly tell the difference between these two sounds, even after trying to isolate the consonant in the above words. (She is a native Japanese speaker learning Mandarin, and I am the opposite.)

Are we imagining things, or is there actually a slight difference in [ɕ] between languages? If the latter, are they marked as identical in the IPA because no single language differentiates between the Mandarin [ɕ] and the Japanese [ɕ]?

Comment: Great question! I hope you get a good answer here, but if not, you may also consider trying the Linguistics Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all IPA transcriptions, for a consonant to be regarded as the [voiceless alveolo-palatal sibilant ɕ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolo-palatal_sibilant), it only needs to fulfil certain conditions (which are listed under the 'Features' section in that Wikipedia link). This does not mean that the set of conditions reduce to a unique phoneme; it is highly possible that the variety of actual sounds fulfilled by the transcription ɕ can be differentiated by someone with more sensitive hearing abilities. The following is a comparison between Mandarin **xī** and Japanese **し**:

- [xī](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Zh-x%C4%AB.ogg)
- [し](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Ja-Shi.oga)

As a native speaker of Mandarin, I cannot tell the difference between the consonants, but if you **can** tell the difference, I suspect that you may hear subtle differences in the pronunciation of ɕ in the other language audio examples in that Wikipedia link.

Comment: How do you not tell the difference between the X and the Sh sound difference from both? Unless you are the kind of chinese who pronounces your X until it sounds like an Sh I think they are very distinct.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. You started off by comparing X with Sh then ended by comparing X with S. Which one is it?

Comment: Just a typo. There's only one comparison. I can't see how they are similar at all unless your particular local chinese dialect/accent affects the X pronunciation to the extent of it becoming Sh. But then again, majority of mandarin speakers shouldn't have problems with differentiating them imo.

Comment: I have no particular local dialect or accent. I don't find them at all different, and IPA agrees. I also don't understand your comparison, as the Mandarin pinyin transcription "sh" sounds nothing like the initial Japanese consonant of "shi", while the pinyin transcription "x" sounds highly similar, at least to me. I've also had a native Japanese teacher who once complimented me by saying that I "have no accent", and I don't pronounce Chinese "x" and Japanese "sh" differently, so if there is a difference then I'd wager that it is very small, or it is you who has the incorrect pronunciation.

Comment: For me it's the opposite, I pronounce chinese Shi like the Japanese Shi and my Xi is distinct from Shi.
E.g. Shi (Sh-rr) for 十  is very different from my Xi (S-ee) Wang希望. Of the two I think the Sh for Chinese is much closer to Japanese Shi than Xi. But you see it the opposite? That is confusing. I don't suppose there's a confusion of pinyin romanization? If my examples were erroneous romanization do point them out but I don't think I made any. Other than the obvious difficulty to write out the voicings for words like Chinese 十.

Comment: If after seeing my examples and you truly pronounce your "Xi"s like Shi then wouldn't your 希望 (Sh-ee W-ah-ng), thus making your "Xi"s have zero difference from your "Sh"s then? 
Either way I just found it curious there could be a confusion. I agree more with the question asker that they are very distinct. Not putting fault on the pronunciation, just curious of the reason for the confusion. Your Japanese pronunciation is at no fault apparently, so I was asking more on the Chinese end. For it to sound like the Japanese Shi naturally is an oddity to me.

Comment: 希望 is most definitely not pronounced "S-ee Wang" in Standard Mandarin! That would be what you would call a "regional pronunciation" or "accent"! Please refer back to the example given in my answer for how to pronounce "xī" (which is an exact Pinyin transcription of 希). Note that the recorded audio is from Wikimedia foundation, and is the standard Mandarin pronunciation.

Chinese Pinyin "Shi" is pronounced with a Voiceless Retroflex Sibilant /ʂ/, listen to https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Voiceless_retroflex_sibilant.ogg. It emphatically does not sound like Japanese し.

Comment: And yes, 希望 is pronounced (Sh-ee W-ah-ng) in Standard Mandarin. Please listen carefully to e.g. news anchors if you don't believe me.

Comment: This is interesting. I am actually Chinese but from South East Asia. I know it's pronounced that way but I thought it would be in the minority and not the other way round. No I believe you. I noticed mainland Chinese speakers tend to add extra "h" sound to a lot of their words when pinyin-wise it might be lacking. Like "Zh" when the pinyin is only "Z". So as a final question to you, what is the difference then between "Xi" and "Shi" to you if you pronounce the X and Sh the same? Just to differentiate between Xi 希 and Shi十 where Xi has the vowel is going "ee" and Shi has the vowel going "shh"?

Comment: Pinyin X and pinyin Sh are very different. Pinyin X and Japanese Sh are almost identical. Could you clarify which one you're asking about? I suspect part of the confusion here is due to us misunderstanding one-another. Note that pinyin x (e.g. 西), pinyin s (e.g. 四), and pinyin sh (e.g. 誰) are completely different sounds, and native Mandarin (mainland) speakers, myself included, will clearly articulate the difference.

Comment: I understand the differences. It seems we are just in disagreement because of our local differences in pronunciation. Well probably South East Asians uses Xi with the "see" pronunciation. Because we will never add so much "ssh" sound by adding "h" sound to our x's to make our x (e.g. 西) Xi become Shi like Japaneseし. Our "see" will not be mistaken as a "shi" ever with or without an accent. Thanks anyway for the effort in explaining.

Comment: So, my current understanding now is that you would pronounce pinyin 'x' and pinyin 's' identically. That's okay; It's impossible to confuse, because syllables which start with standard mandarin 'x' and syllables which start with standard mandarin 's' never overlap in their trailing part anyway. It's a redundant difference from the point of information theory, so even us mainlanders won't misunderstand you guys.